# ddply to ksmooth function

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame with several columns. the relevant three are `chr`, `pos` and `ratio`. I want to use `ddply` to `ksmooth` based on `chr` (chromosome) but keep getting a wrong data frame with lots of `NA` values. Here is my reproducible data frame:

```
d=data.frame(chr=c(rep.int(1,24),rep.int(2,15),rep.int(3,30),rep.int(4,20),rep.int(5,11)),
             pos=c(sort(sample(1:1000, size = 24, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE), sort(sample(1:1000, size = 15, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE), sort(sample(1:1000, size = 30, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE), sort(sample(1:1000, size = 20, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE), sort(sample(1:1000, size = 11, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE)),
             ratio=seq(1:100))
```

and `ddply` function

```
f <- ddply(d, .(chr),
  function(e) { 
       as.data.frame(ksmooth(e$pos,e$ratio,"normal",bandwidth=10))
  })
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help,
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing related to `plyr::ddply`. The issue is with `ksmooth`. You want:

```
ksmooth(e$pos, e$ratio, "normal", bandwidth=10, x.points = e$pos)
```

Read `?ksmooth` for what `x.points` means. By default, this is `NULL`, and `ksmooth` will use `n.points` instead. This is the source of all your trouble.

Comment: Thanks Zheyuan but nop, I want each position (that would be a SNP location on the x axis) to plot against some ratio variable (y axis) but to do this for each independent chr. The way it is now, I get 500 lines instead of the expected 100 as the original data frame

Comment: yap you are right, the bandwidth is wrong, but this is not my main problem. the issue is that the out put has 500 entries rather than 100 (for this example). As for the second question, I'm not sure I understood it but I'd like to ksmooth to take pos as x and ratio as y and ddply to apply it to each chr. Hope it's a bit more clear.